# Are there any non-Western wizarding communities that widely adopted any Wand-like instrument the way Western wizards adopted the wand?

Tags: harry-potter

Reference these related questions:
[What objects can be used as wand substitutes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20442/what-objects-can-be-used-as-wand-substitutes)
[Are there any other tools wizards can use as they would a wand?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160573/are-there-any-other-tools-wizards-can-use-as-they-would-a-wand)

Western civilization describes the development of human civilization beginning in Ancient Greece, and generally spreading westwards. The use of wands in the Western world can trace [the first instance of magic wand use to Circe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circe) in Homer’s *Odyssey*, [who used her wand to transform Odysseus's men into animals.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odyssey)

[image: Circe with wand]

Within the Harry Potter universe, the history of wand use likewise appears to follow a Western-centric fictional history. J.K. Rowling herself confirms this in her writings.

[From Uagadou (“Wag-ado”):](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/uagadou), she writes:

> The wand is a European invention…

[And from 1920’s Wizarding America](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/1920s-wizarding-america-en), she writes:

> Legislation introduced at the end of the nineteenth century meant that every member of the magical community in America was required to carry a ‘wand permit’, a measure that was intended to keep tabs on all magical activity and identify the perpetrators by their wands.

Like most prohibition-type legislation, it appears that the American legislators widely conflated wand ownership with “all magical activity.”

[From the Potter Wiki:](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Wand)

> Wands were developed in Europe at an unknown point, though it is known that it was in the B.C. era. The Ollivander family started manufacturing wands in 382 B.C…
> At an unknown point in history, wands were introduced to Asia. Cherry wand masters received special prestige at Mahoutokoro school in Japan.
> In the 20th century, wands were introduced to Africa, where they were less commonly used compared to other parts of the world.

Given that magic long predated Greece and Western influence, and many cultures outside of the Western world developed their magic without a basis in wand-use, are there any other wizarding communities which adopted their own specific version of quasi-sentient magical instrument in such widespread use as wands have become in Western wizarding cultures through which a witch or wizard channelled their magical powers to centralise the effects for more complex results? Or is there something unique about the status of wands within Potterverse that perhaps institutionalizes Western-centric wand use into the fabric of Rowling’s world-building?

### Are there other cultures around the world whose wizarding community has widely adopted their own specific channeling instrument other than a wand?

Comment: I don't know about in-universe, but [Ancient Egyptians used amulets](https://www.bbc.co.uk/history/ancient/egyptians/magic_01.shtml)

Comment: @Righter The New Alexandria School of Enlightenment teaching amulet use based on amulet iconography in Egyptian lore and culture would be an ideal answer to this question; but alas, I’m not sure if any of what I just wrote is true within Potter canon.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staff_of_Moses https://collections.mfa.org/objects/355087/wand-in-the-form-of-a-twoheaded-serpent;jsessionid=7207DB90F4659E96BEBFC14EE046BBA4

Comment: @luchasnachmann This traditional orthodox Jewish wizards using staves to honor Moses, or Egyptian wizards using pre-European snake wands to honor their ancient society would be perfect answers if those were true in Potterverse.